# Bash Script error: "syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/backup")"

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I was trying to make a small script to check if backup drive is fine and its disk usage details, and to add it to nagios as an active check in servers. Once I written one, I got some unknown errors that I don't to correct.

Script is:

```
#!/bin/sh

BACKUP_DRIVE='/backup'

if [[ "$( grep $BACKUP_DRIVE /etc/fstab | awk '{print $2}')" -ne "0" ]]; then 

    if [[ "$( df -h | grep $BACKUP_DRIVE | awk '{print $6}')" -ne "0" ]]; then

        if [[ "$( df -h|grep backup|awk '{print $5}' | cut -d "%" -f1)" -ge "95" ]]; then
            echo "CRITICAL: Backup Drive usage exceeded 95%"
        fi
    else
        echo "CRITICAL: Backup Drive not mounted"
    fi
else
    echo "CRITICAL: Backup Drive not added in fstab"
fi
```

Error is:

```
# sh /usr/local/src/backupcheck.sh
/usr/local/src/backupcheck.sh: line 6: [[: /backup: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/backup")
CRITICAL: Backup Drive not added in fstab
```

It's getting error at the first if condition itself and not getting into the inner if conditions.

Is there any corrections need to be done at point where variable $BACKUP_DRIVE mentioned? Please help as I am a beginner to bash scripting.

Comment: why are you using /bin/sh instead of /bin/bash

Comment: The repeated `grep | awk`, `df | awk`, `... | awk | cut`, and similar usage in here is inefficient, hard-to-read, and generally silly. Using the shell's `read` builtin to parse these contents a whole line at a time would be considerably simpler and more readable.

Comment: ...also, combining `[[ ]]` with `-ge` is silly as well -- any shell supporting `[[ ]]` will also support `(( ))`, in which the far-more-readable `>=` can be used for numeric comparisons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ***immediate* issue** - likely the one triggering the syntax error - is:

You're using shebang `#!/bin/sh`, which is NOT guaranteed to be `bash` (and even if it is, it behaves differently), yet you're using bash-specific syntax (`[[ ... ]]`).

- Use `#!/bin/bash` as the shebang instead.
- When explicitly starting a script with an executable, use `bash`, not `sh`; in your example: `bash /usr/local/src/backupcheck.sh`

Alternatively, with the shebang as is and if you want to be able to invoke your script explicitly with `sh`:

- Rewrite your script to use POSIX features only, which in the case at hand requires replacing `[[ ... ]]` with `[ ... ]` (but in the general case typically requires more changes).

You can only get away without rewriting if you know for sure that `sh` is actually `bash` on your system and you do not need the script to be portable (run on other platforms).

---

However, there are also **issues with your conditionals**:

It looks like your first 2 conditionals are meant to only test whether the enclosed command *succeeds* or not.

Generally, you do not need `[[ ... ]]` for such tests at all, and instead simply use the command directly with `if`, possibly negated with `!`, and with output suppressed as needed with `>/dev/null` or `2>/dev/null`:

Thus, instead of your command:

```
if [[ "$( grep $BACKUP_DRIVE /etc/fstab | awk '{print $2}')" -ne "0" ]]; then
```

you should use:

```
if grep $BACKUP_DRIVE /etc/fstab >/dev/null; then
```

`grep` will indicate having found (at least) a match with exit code `0`, which is (also) success from `if`'s perspective. Thus, effectively, the `if` command's body will be executed if the backup drive *exists*.

*Note that I've removed the `awk` command*, as it (a) isn't necessary for the test and (b) actually *defeats* the test in that it will cause the overall result to be `0` (success), even if the `grep` command failed.

Similarly, your 2nd conditional should read:

```
if df -h | grep $BACKUP_DRIVE >/dev/null; then
```

Finally, your 3rd conditional is correct *in principle*: it captures stdout output from the pipeline and compares it to a percentage number (though double-quoting the number is not necessary and potentially confusing).
However, you accidentally hard-coded the drive name, so instead it should be:

```
if [[ "$(df -h | grep $BACKUP_DRIVE | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d "%" -f1)" -ge 95 ]]; then
```

---

Finally:

- You should output your error messages to `stderr` by redirecting the `echo` commands with `2>/dev/null`; similarly, you should use `exit 1` (or any other nonzero exit code) to exit in case of error, so as to properly signal an error condition.
- As @Charles Duffy points out in comments on the OP, there is potential for making your commands more efficient.

Comment: The point is valid, but `[[ ]]` should also work with `ksh` and other `ksh`-derived shells, like `zsh`.

Comment: @TrippKinetics: Yes, it works with other shells too, but (a) the question is tagged `bash`, and (b) the point is that the only features you're _guaranteed_ to get when you use `sh` are POSIX-only features.

Comment: Then the suggestion would be to use `[]` rather than `[[]]`, wouldn't it?

Comment: @TrippKinetics: Because of the `bash` tag it's fair to assume that the _intent is to use `bash`_ (which is preferable, due to its superior feature set compared to a POSIX-only shell). Should it be the case that _it is `sh` must be targeted_, then yes, the script would have to be rewritten to use POSIX features only, such as replacing `[[ ... ]]` with `[ ... ]`.

Comment: The question seems to imply that the script is being explicitly run using `sh`--`# sh /usr/local/src/backupcheck.sh`--so this answer is spot on.

Comment: There are two options: 1. Use bash. 2. Don't use bash. For option 1, the shebang needs to be `#!/bin/bash`, and the script should not be invoked as `sh script-name.sh`. For option 2, the script should not use `[[`...`]]`. Either option is perfectly valid.

Comment: Thank you @mklement0 , that was an awesome response from you.

Answer (score 1):

At some point, it's trying to evaluate the `$BACKUP_DRIVE` parameter as a math expression.  Try this instead:

```
grep $BACKUP_DRIVE /etc/fstab | awk '{print $2}'
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]] ; then
...
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `evaluate the $BACKUP_DRIVE parameter as a math expression`, but it is true that the _stdout output_ from the entire expression `"$( grep $BACKUP_DRIVE /etc/fstab | awk '{print $2}')"` in the question will be interpreted as a _number_, due to use of the `-ne` operator. Your rewrite makes sense if the intent is to _print command output first_, then _check whether the command succeeded_. However, I suspect that only the latter is needed.